# How to improve the performance of this MongoDB operation?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So on startup for my application, I need to fetch a list of all products the company has. This is a list of only about 60 products.

We need to fetch the entire list, regardless of what a user has purchased, because unpurchased items need to be displayed in a "catalogue" view.

Each document in the `products` collection has a `hasAccess` array property, which is an array of user IDs.

The problem is that these `hasAccess` arrays are sometimes thousands of items long, so the below query is starting to take quite awhile (up to 1 second):

```
const userID = req.user.id

Product.find({}, (err, _products) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    return
  }
  res.json(_products)
}
```

Currently, after performing this query and before returning data to the client, I then check inside a loop of each in `_products`, checking each `product.hasAccess` if it contains the user's ID, and then doing something.

Is there a more performant way of doing this? Is there some way of simply returning a boolean of `product.hasAccess.includes(userID)` instead of having Mongoose return the entire array and then checking myself?

To be clear, it is the Mongoose operation itself that is taking a very long time (hundreds of milliseconds), not my work upon it afterwards. My initial feeling is that most of this time is simply down to the time it takes to parse such large amounts of JSON.

Comment: Better answers will probably come...but one I could think of is actually restructuring your database itself since it's not scalable. Have a database that maps user IDs to product ids is a good start.

Comment: The schema design is questionable, but benchmark if 2 queries are quicker: `find({hasAccess:<userId>}, {hasAccess:0})` and `find({hasAccess:{$not:{$eq:<userId>}}}, {hasAccess:0})`.  so you will have 2 lists and don't retrieve hasAccess array at all.